# Drag and drop playlist in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, playlist

I'm working on a drag and drop project where music clips can be dragged and dropped at various locations. I have the drag and drop figured out but I need to be able to add the clips to a playlist, so they play in order depending on their dropped positions. Does anyone have any experience with this or relevant examples from around the web?

Answer (score 1):

I made a very quick example without using a library.
As a basis I used w3s example: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp
I hope I have been helpful

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        #div1 {
            width: 350px;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
        }

        .list {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin: 10px;
            padding: 5px;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        function allowDrop(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
        }

        function drag(ev) {
            ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
        }

        function drop(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
            ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        }

        function playList() {
            var x = document.getElementsByClassName("list");
            var y = document.getElementById("showList");
            y.innerHTML = "";
            for ( var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                y.innerHTML += x[i].getAttribute("data-path") + "<br>";
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <div id="drag1" class="list" data-path="song1.mp3" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Song 1</div>
        <div id="drag2" class="list" data-path="song2.mp3" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Song 2</div>
        <div id="drag3" class="list" data-path="song3.mp3" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Song 3</div>
        <div id="drag4" class="list" data-path="song4.mp3" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Song 4</div>
    </div>

    <button onclick="playList();">PLAY</button>
        
    <div id="showList"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi and thanks very much for your answer. This is definitely the sort of thing I'm after. I can run your code and I see that the playList function returns a list of the names of the sound files in the dropped order. How can I then play these files one after the other? Thank you so much for your help. Michael

Comment: @Michael, hi, did this script work for you? Were you able to drag mp3 files to the box, have divs created with their filenames and local path?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use jquery ui, something like this.

```js
var dragging=false;
$(".list").draggable({ 
    revert: "valid",
    start: function(event, ui) {
        dragging=true;
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        dragging=false;
    }
});
$(".content-list").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).css('background', 'rgb(0,200,0)');
        if($(ui.draggable).hasClass("list")){
          $(this).append("<div class='row'>"+$(ui.draggable).html()+"</div>");
        }
    },
    over: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).css('background', 'orange');
    },
    out: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).css('background', 'cyan');
    }
});
$(".content-list").sortable();
```

```css
.list{
  border: 2px solid #000;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float:left;
}
.content-list{
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left:60px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
.row{
  border: 2px solid #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="list">1</div>
<div class="list">2</div>
<div class="list">3</div>
<div class="list">4</div>
<div class="list">5</div>
<div class="list">6</div>


<div class="content-list"></div>
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: @Hahuen Hi, thanks for the reply. Does your answer include playing sound files? I can do the drag and drop but I can't get sound files to play depending on the drop positions; in other words a drag and drop playlist. Thank you.

Comment: @Michael When the play button is pressed you can iterate for each item (div) inside the container, and save it into an array. Then you have the completed playlist in the order selected. Also, you have the drop and sort events to refresh the array or save it into the db. To play files, it depends on what plugin you are using.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I was hoping just to use the <audio> tag in html.